# Can I get "--no-install-recommends" behavior with a setting in the Debian "control" file?

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, debian

I'm looking for a way to build direction into my Debian package (say, in the `control` file or elsewhere) that will tell `apt-get install` to behave as though I had included the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

**Back Story**

I manage a package - call it `foo` - that explicitly depends on three other packages (they are `libcuda1-340`, `nvidia-340` and `nvidia-opencl-icd-340`, BTW, if knowing that helps).  When I try to install `foo` using...

```
apt-get install foo
```

...it winds up trying to install a long list of other packages that I don't want, and that in fact break my machine.  I have found that if I instead do...

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends foo
```

...it installs `foo` and the three explicit dependencies and nothing else, and that gets me the end result I want.

Perfect!

**But here's the twist: I can't use the `--no-install-recommends` flag.**

That's because...

1. the `apt-get install` is being done for me by a tool that I don't really control,
2. that tool also installs many other packages besides `foo` for me, and
3. I only want the `--no-install-depends` behavior with respect to package `foo`.  In all other cases I want to bring the dependencies in, too.

**The question**: So, is there some directive I can put in package `foo`'s `debian/control` file or elsewhere that would get me this behavior, only for package `foo`?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish the same thing on our Trusty LTS servers, I put these in /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
```

Similarly, for "suggested" packages

```
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's a possibility.  But wouldn't it apply to all packages?  Is there a way to limit its effects to the one package I want to do that way?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your #3.  I've personally never seen a conditional config for apt based on the package name. Maybe there's a config for the tool (you didn't name it)

Comment: The tool is something we wrote here.  So far it's nice and clean and generic and I want to avoid complicating it if I don't have to.  We'll see what happens.  I may have to!

Answer (score 1):

Use a "conflicts" and/or "breaks" control field listing to prevent installation of packages that will cause breakage.

> Packages can declare in their control file that they have certain relationships to other packages - for example, that they may not be installed at the same time as certain other packages, and/or that they depend on the presence of others.
>
> This is done using the Depends, Pre-Depends, Recommends, Suggests, Enhances, Breaks and Conflicts control fields.

- Source: [Debian Policy Manual, Chapter 7](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)

This means that you will need to narrow down the list of packages to those that actually cause breakage.

You, as the packager, don't get to decide the apt settings on the end user's system.